# Delete row from datatable where first column does not contain (some string)

Tags: c#, datatable

I have DataTable with the following columns:

```
ClientID date numberOfTransactions price
```

ClientID is of type string and I need to ensure that its contents include "A-" and "N6" for every value in the table.

I need to delete all rows from the DataTable where this first column (ClientID) does not contain both "A-" **and** "N6" (some totals and other unnecessary data).  How can I select and delete these rows specifically from the DataTable?

I know this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) // Loop over the rows.
    {

        //Here should come part "if first column contains mentioned values
    }
```

I also know this

```
If (string.Contains("A-") == true &&  string.Contains("N6") == true)

{
//Do something
}
```

I need help how to implement this for first column of each row.

Comment: What query have you tried ..? also what DataBase are you using SQL Server, MYSQL etc...?

Comment: This question is too vague; gives us more details, please

Comment: I believe the OP just wants to remove certain DataRows from the DataTable.Rows collection (in memory), so knowing where the data is coming from might actually be irrelevant (hence his/her confusion).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

**EDIT:** Totally messed up that last line, so if you tried it, try it now that I made it not stupid.  =)

```
List<int> IndicesToRemove = new List<int>();
DataTable table = new DataTable(); //Obviously, your table will already exist at this point
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
   if (!(row["ClientID"].ToString().Contains("A-") && row["ClientID"].ToString().Contains("N6")))
      IndicesToRemove.Add(table.Rows.IndexOf(row));
}
IndicesToRemove.Sort();
for (int i = IndicesToRemove.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) table.Rows.RemoveAt(IndicesToRemove[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

try using this,

assuming dt as your Datatabe object and ClientID as your first column (hence using ItemArray[0])

```
for(int i=0; i<dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  temp = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();

if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(temp, "A-", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) || System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(temp, "N6", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
   {
     dt.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
     i--;
   }
 }
```

Simple and straight forward solution... hope it helps

Comment: If you do it this way, don't you risk skipping over rows during your iteration?  Let's say i = 2 and you find a row that needs to be removed.  You remove row (2) which adjusts all other rows' indices - but now i = 3, so the **new** (2) didn't get evaluated, right?

Comment: Agreed, removing from a collection while iterating through it will cause problems.

Comment: @C.Barlow, you are right. my mistake. forgot to add one more line that was : "i--;" That's it.

Comment: I was facing the same problem, found this answer, works like a charm :)

Answer (score 2):

this should be more efficient, both in lines of Code and Time, try this :)

```
for(int x=0; x<table.Rows.Count;)
{
   if (!table.Rows[x].ItemArray[0].contains("A-") && !table.Rows[x].ItemArray[0].contains("N6"))
      table.Rows.RemoveAt(x);
   else x++;
}
```

Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

*Preface: [C.Barlow's existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003859/delete-row-from-datatable-where-first-column-does-not-contain-some-string/9004798#9004798) is awesome, this is just another route someone could take.*

This is one way to do it where you never have to loop all the way through the original table (by taking advantage of the [`DataTable.Select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) method):

```
DataTable table = new DataTable(); // This would be your existing DataTable
// Grab only the rows that meet your criteria using the .Select() method
DataRow[] newRows = table.Select("ClientID LIKE '%A-%' AND ClientID LIKE '%N6%'");
// Create a new table with the same schema as your existing one.
DataTable newTable = table.Clone();
foreach (DataRow r in newRows)
{
    // Dump the selected rows into the table.
    newTable.LoadDataRow(r.ItemArray, true);
}
```

And now you have a `DataTable` with only the rows you want.  If necessary, at this point you could clear out the original table and replace it with the contents of the new one:

```
table.Clear();
table = newTable.Copy();
```

---

**Edit:** I thought of a memory optimization last night, you can just overwrite the existing table once you have the rows you need, which avoids the need for the temporary table.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable(); // This would be your existing DataTable
// Grab only the rows that meet your criteria using the .Select() method
DataRow[] newRows = table.Select("ClientID LIKE '%A-%' AND ClientID LIKE '%N6%'");
// Clear out the old table
table.Clear();
foreach (DataRow r in newRows)
{
    // Dump the selected rows into the table.
    table.LoadDataRow(r.ItemArray, true);
}
```

Comment: Nice!  +1 for efficiency and being generally sassy!